# Datetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00 using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm running xampp 3.3.0, mysql 8.0. In my database, there is a column datetime with type "datetime". I'm trying to insert data in it with CURRENT_TIMESTAP.
Example of query:

```
INSERT INTO `statistics` (`chat_id`, `user_id`, `message_id`, `datetime`, `ai_unique`) VALUES ('988', '767', '98765', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', NULL);
```

It inserts, but I'm getting

```
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'datetime' at row 1
```

And instead of current timestamp, it inserts 0000-00-00 00:00:00
Some time ago it worked just fine, but now it's inserting 0000-00-00 00:00:00. If I manually write a date here like 2023-01-11 22:52:01 it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

`'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` (with single-quotes) is a string. It doesn't have a datetime value. MySQL makes an effort to convert the string to a datetime, just as it would convert the string `'2023-01-24 13:09:00'` to a datetime. But the string you used cannot be converted in this way.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (a pseudoclumn with no single-quotes) has a datetime value.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` (a function) also returns a datetime value.